# Azure VM repository for different resource groups

Tags: azure

I would like to make VM in Azure witch gonna be repository in one resource group and VMs from other resource groups could access to this repository.
Ona important thing there are same VMs in different RG (clones of one RG)

Can I use Blob storage that would be seen by VMs in few RG?

Answer (score 0):

Azure resource group is a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution.
Resource Group does not block traffic or prevent communication between Azure resources.

If you want two virtual machines to communicate between each other, create them in same Virtual Network and same Subnetwork.

[image]

Comment: That's very usefull, but can I connect VM's from different RGs to one more Virtual Network(They have already one VN inside every RG)?

Comment: Resource group is only a container that holds resources for an Azure solution. If you want to connect two VMs from different Virtual Networks see Peering https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Comment: Also VMs can communicate via Public IP addresses. You should allow access to appropriate ports using NSG. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview